How to kill all the threads in ThreadPools
How can I kill all the threads in ThreadPools(threadpoolexecutor) when one thread finishes?

You cannot. Well, except by killing the whole process. You can, however, cancel any pending futures and then wait for any currently executing futures to finish.
If that is not good enough then you can try cooperative cancellation. Whereby a future periodically checks for an event while executing, and if the event is triggered then it exits early. This cancellation is entirely cooperative, and if the thread/future gets into trouble and hangs elsewhere in the code then you're out of luck.
from time import sleep
from threading import Event
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

stop = Event()

def job(name):
    print(f'job {name} starting')
    while True:
        if stop.is_set():
            print(f'job {name} exiting...')
            return
        # do something
        print(f'job {name} doing something')
        sleep(0.3)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    print('starting worker thread')
    fut_foo = executor.submit(job, name='foo')
    fut_bar = executor.submit(job, name='bar')
    sleep(1)
    assert fut_foo.running() and not fut_foo.done()
    assert not fut_bar.running() and not fut_bar.done()
    print('asking futures to stop')
    stop.set()
    fut_bar.cancel()
    print('waiting for futures to finish')
    print(f'{fut_foo.done()=} and {fut_bar.done()=}')
assert fut_foo.done() and fut_bar.done() and fut_bar.cancelled()
print('done')


